# How to get my div to be 100% of browser?

Tags: html, css

I have created a div in html with an image and come text, I added 100% to the width of the div in the css and I also added a background colour but for some reason the div is not 100% of the browser and I can't see what I am doing wrong.

```css
#container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#pic {
  padding-left: 450px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
#about {
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 100px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="pic">

    <img class="errorimage" src="IMG_4847.png" alt="" title="">

  </div>

  <div id="about">


    <h1 class="name">Rebekah</h1>


    <h2 class="name2">Web Desgin. Google Adwords. Google Analytics.</h2>


  </div>
```

Comment: *Always* reset the document padding , like this `html,body{margin:0;padding:0}`

Comment: could you make an image of the desired result?

Comment: don't know how sorry

Comment: Alright,  let's do this.  Go to the link I gave you in my answer and input your code there replicating the error.  That way we can see where is coming from.

Comment: use `vw` css units

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it's not 100% is because the div is running into the padding of the `#about` div. If you remove the left and right padding it will fix the problem.

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}    

#about {
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/orLnbq5n/1/)

Comment: Is there something wrong with the fiddle I provided? What seems to be off?

Comment: If you could, please tell me exactly what you are trying to achieve so I can help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following CSS:

```
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#pic img{
  padding-top: 40px;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

I took some of the code out in my demo to show you more clearly. Here is the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGbgxg)

You were close. The width to 100% needs to be in the actual img. And the html and body margins and paddings needs to be reset since the come natively with some padding already for you

Answer (score 1):

Your div does not take 100% of the browser because it is taking the 100% of it's parent element.. which is `#container`. You can fix this by adding this rule to your parent element `#container`

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; //this is if you really wish to make your div to fully take 100% of browser
}
```

although `#container` will take in this case the 100% of the parent element.. so you would have to check that upward parents have the size you wish to achieve

Comment: @becky did you check the elements that are containing `#container` has the proper size?.. check if this inherits from `body` or another element that does not have the size you look for

Answer (score 1):

I placed the background image directly to html (better than body as it's always at least the height of the browser window)

```css
html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background: url('http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/branches/211/5507692-cat-m.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: atuo;
}

#about{
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id ="about">
      <h1 class ="name">Rebekah</h1>
      <h2 class ="name2">Web Desgin. Google Adwords. Google Analytics.</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what result are you after, but this now has full page width - *after removing lots of padding right and left, because browsers *adds* `padding-left` and `padding-right` values to the width, so having `width:100%` with padding-left:450px` means the total computer width will be 100% + 450px.. for a screen of 1200px width that means the total width will be 1650px instead of 1200px.

So remove these lines from your CSS:

```
#pic {
  padding-left: 450px; /*remove*/
/*****
#about {
  padding-left: 50px; /* remove */
  padding-right: 100px /* remove */
```

---

Also if you want to give the image an absolute position then you position it with `top:` , `left:` , `right:` or `bottom:` not with padding and margin

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/PZbMvp?editors=110)

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px skyblue solid;
}
#pic {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
#pic img {
  width: 100%;
}
#about {
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="pic">
    <img class="errorimage" src="//placehold.it/1000x300/00ff00/ffffff?text=banner" alt="" title="">
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    <h1 class="name">Rebekah</h1>
    <h2 class="name2">Web Desgin. Google Adwords. Google Analytics.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```